# React navigation replace action doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a stackNavigator that contains 4 screens:

```
const stack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        S1: {
            screen: S1,
        },
        S2: {
            screen: S2,
        },
        S3: {
            screen: S3,
        },
        S4: {
            screen: S4,
        },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Bienvenue',
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        },
    },
);
```

navigating from S1 --> S2 --> S3 , i want to go back to S2 by replacing S2 screen, **but the navigation.replace doesn't replace the screen, it create new one on top of S2 !!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i found is by passing a method in params
let's say i have a state in S2:

```
const [somthing, setSomthing]= useState(false);
```

when navigating to S3, i set: `navigation.navigate('S3', {SetSomthing}}`
and in S3 i get the param: `const SetSomthing = navigation.getParams('SetSomthing');`

and when i want to go back to S2:

```
setSomthing(true);
navigation.pop();
```

Comment: How can we use pop in Typescript? I get this ```Property 'pop' does not exist on type 'NavigationProp<Record<string, object | undefined>, string, NavigationState, {}, {}>'.ts(2339)```

Comment: @jnl The problem is in the navigation object type, but if you make a log of it you will see the pop function, so it's only a declaration problem

Comment: and...is there a possible solution to it?

Answer (score 3):

Navigation.replace() will replace your current stack scene with the new one. So if you are on S3, and call navigation.replace('S2'), then what you are doing is replacing S3 in the stack with S2, but still leaving the earlier S2 in the stack. This results in...

S1 > S2 > S2

If you want to go back to S2, I would recommend using the following if you are on S3:

```
navigation.goBack()
```

Or alternatively, you could use the following from S3 / S4 to 'pop' back to S2.

```
navigation.pop('S2')
```

Hope this helps. If I've misunderstood something about what you want to achieve then please let me know .

Comment: and i can use .navigate to, but i want to pass some params back to S2, how can i pass them ?

Comment: navigation.navigate('S1', {myParam: "Hey!" }

Then you can retreive it by: navigation.getParam('myParam', '');

- The empty quotes are used to set a default value in case the param is missing

Comment: when you use navigate() to go back to an already existing screen it will not rerender and then it will not read any params.

Comment: How can we use pop in Typescript? I get this ```Property 'pop' does not exist on type 'NavigationProp<Record<string, object | undefined>, string, NavigationState, {}, {}>'.ts(2339)```